# Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression - After WordPress Update

Tags: jquery, wordpress

After updating WordPress to Version 4.6 (jQuery Update), this File is not more Working.
With the old jQuery its working.

```
function _removerlay (object) {
  jQuery('#x-widgets-list .loader').remove();
   var _elem1 = "<div id='x-pbwp-outerlay'></div>",
       _elem2 = "<div id='x-widgets-list'></div>";
   $elem = object.closest("div[class*='x-wrapp-class-']") ;
   $elem.unwrap(_elem2);
   $elem.unwrap(_elem1);
   $elem.hide()
}

function _createpopshort (object) {
    var _structure = "<div id='x-pbwp-outerlay'><div id='x-widgets-list'></div></div>",
    $elem = jQuery('#x-widgets-list');
    var a = object.closest(".column-in").next();
    jQuery(a).wrap(_structure).delay(100).fadeIn(150);
}
```

Error in Console:

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:

Comment: ANy idea what line?

Comment: `$elem.unwrap(_elem2);` _elem2 is suposed to be a selector and you are passing in an element?

Comment: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: <div id='x-widgets-list'></div>

Answer (score 0):

unwrap expects a selector, not a string that looks like an element

```
var _elem1 = "#x-pbwp-outerlay",
    _elem2 = "#x-widgets-list";
```

Comment: Now i can press save and change something, much thanks. But adding new Container is not working, without any Error.